# SQL*Plus via Shellscript using WHENEVER OSERROR

Tags: oracle, shell, sqlplus

I need to use

```
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
```

but to make the exit only when it is an invalid user or password. They will know how?

```
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s /nolog << EOF
WHENEVER OSERROR EXIT 9;
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE;
connect $schema/$pass@$db
@$dir_sql $schema;
EOF
```

Comment: `exit sql.sqlcode` is not advisable in Unix/Linux environments, as return codes are typically 8 bit integers and therefore can't represent a `sqlcode` value higher than 255 without wrapping back around to 0.

Comment: Please explain your question in more detail. What you mean - "but to make the exit only when it is an invalid user or password"? What should happen if another error occurred?